# How to detect user in app subscription cancel or renew in android?

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

> How to detect user in app subscription cancel or  renew in android
> java. please tell step by step i am new android developer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Google Play provides a purchase token back to the purchasing app through the In-app Billing API. Your apps can store the token locally or pass it to your backend servers, which can then use it to validate or cancel the subscription remotely using the Google Play Developer API.[User Billing Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

if the user Cancels subscription purchase. The subscription remains valid until its expiration time.[Purchases. subscriptions: cancel Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel)

Also, you can try API for in-app purchase in android https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview